# Huffman Encoding in MATLAB- Finding size of the dictionary

Tags: matlab

I have implemented Huffman encoding in MATLAB and later it will be implemented in FPGA. In hardware, each value is represented by 16 bits. Now I want to find the compression ratio achieved after encoding the data. As the distionary also has to be transferred with the data for decoding, should I include its size in the total size of the data? If yes, how should I do it?

Here is how the dictionary (16-bit signed integers along with their codewords) looks like:

```
-88     [1,1,1,0,1,0,1]    
-76     [1,1,1,0,1,0,0]
-66     [1,1,1,0,1,1,1]
-59     [1,1,1,0,1,1,0]
-48     [1,1,1,0,0,0,1]
-38     [1,1,0,0,1,0,1]
-30     [1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
-27     [1,1,1,0,0,1,1]
-23     [1,1,1,0,0,1,0]
-18     [1,1,1,1,1,0,1]
-9      [1,1,1,1,1,0,0]
-8      [1,1,0,0,1,0,0]
-7      [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
-5      [1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
-4      [1,1,0,0,1,1,1]
-3      [1,1,1,1,0,0,1]
-2      [1,1,1,1,0,0,0]
-1      [1,0,1]
 0      0
 1      [1,0,0]
2       [1,1,0,0,1,1,0]
4       [1,1,0,0,0,0,1]
6       [1,1,1,1,0,1,1]
7       [1,1,1,1,0,1,0]
8       [1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]
9       [1,1,0,0,0,0,0]
12      [1,1,0,1,1,1]
13      [1,1,0,0,0,1,1]
15      [1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0]
16      [1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1]
22      [1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0]
23      [1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1]
27      [1,1,0,0,0,1,0]
30      [1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]
31      [1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1]
35      [1,1,0,1,1,0,1]
41      [1,1,0,1,1,0,0]
83      [1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0]
```

Secondly, I do not want to send the whole tree (as it would take more space), So can you suggest me an easy way of doing that? I have read Deflate and Adaptive Huffman already.

Thank you!